# CScrollBar/MFC: flickering while move the thumb slider

Tags: c++, mfc

I implemented a **MFC application** which displays a chart. There are data points (e.g. 2000) where a subset of them will be displayed in the chart. This subset must be changed with a scroll bar. So I added in my dialog class the `CScrollBar` class and listen to the `ON_WM_HSCROLL` event which calls the `OnHScroll` method.

```
void CChartWithRealTimeDataDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    UINT nCurrentPos;

    nCurrentPos = pScrollBar->GetScrollPos();

    // nCurrentPos = m_X_Axis_Scrollbar->GetScrollPos();

    bool bDoRepaint = false;

    switch (nSBCode) 
    {
    //case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            nCurrentPos = nPos;
            pScrollBar->SetScrollPos (nPos);
            bDoRepaint = true;
        break;

    case SB_LINELEFT:

            nCurrentPos = (UINT)(std::max( (int)0, (int)nCurrentPos-1));
            pScrollBar->SetScrollPos (nCurrentPos);
            bDoRepaint = true;
        break;

    case SB_LINERIGHT:
            nCurrentPos = std::min((UINT)(m_ChartControl.getTotalEnd()), nCurrentPos+1);
            pScrollBar->SetScrollPos (nCurrentPos);
            bDoRepaint = true;
        break;

    case SB_PAGELEFT:
        nCurrentPos = (UINT)(std::max( (int)0, (int)nCurrentPos-10));
        pScrollBar->SetScrollPos (nCurrentPos);
        bDoRepaint = true;
        break;

    case SB_PAGERIGHT:
            nCurrentPos = std::min( (UINT)(m_ChartControl.getTotalEnd()), nCurrentPos+10);
            pScrollBar->SetScrollPos (nCurrentPos);
            bDoRepaint = true;
        break;
    }

    if ( bDoRepaint )
    {
        m_ChartControl.setShift(nCurrentPos);
        Invalidate();
    }

    CDialogEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

If the user moves the thumb slider every time the whole window will be repainted and a flickering begins.

Is there a way to avoid the flickering?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Since the drawing is done by m_ChartControl then you should be calling m_ChartControl.Invalidate(), not the dialog's Invalidate.

If you have the source code for m_ChartControl then see this article and its class CMemDC to prevent flickering in the chart control.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC

Comment: Hi ScottMcP-MVP, thank you for your answer. I changed it to m_ChartControl.Invalidate() and I added the "memory DC" class from Keith Rule (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC). And it works: No more flickering. Thank you again.